# How to define a variable in heap memory in a struct with C++?

Tags: c++

I have 2 Structures, Color one:

```
struct Color
{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
};
```

And the Image structure:

```
struct matrixImage
{
    Image Img;
    struct Color T[MAX][MAX];
    int Width;
    int Height;
};
```

In `T` table, I am storing the pixels of an image. But the maximum size of the array is to low(on stack), so I can't store every pixel of the image. I know how to define an array in Heap like this

->  `struct Color *newTable = new struct Color[anyNumber];`

But how can I write this in `struct matrixImage`, any help?

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use `c++`. A proper `c++` solution would use std::vector.

Comment: Do it via a constructor for the struct.

Comment: little more insight how to do it?

Comment: std:vector<Color> T;

Comment: I am just starting with c++, I didn't know about std::vector, yet...

Comment: @drescherjm I've seen this suggestion a few annoying times. The question is not about which data structure to use for a particular case, it's about how to allocate a variable (array) on the heap. Just answer if you know the answer, otherwise ignore and go ahead.

Comment: That is what `std::vector` will do. Of course I know the pre-standard way to do this. I have been a `c++` programmer for around 30 years.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, probably, but from the OP's question it seems he wants to do it "manually", so let him do it manually. You can also suggest "better" alternatives, but you should focus first on addressing his particular issue.

Comment: @nbro: That's an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Which assumption?

Comment: @nbro: That the OP wants to do it manually.

Comment: Guys, I didn't learn about std::vector, I need to work with what I know, a little push will help very much even if it's not the best solution you may think for it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The fact that he mentions `struct Color *newTable = new struct Color[anyNumber];`, from my perspective, alludes to the fact that he potentially wants to do a similar thing but "inside the struct".

Comment: yes indeed, but how?

Comment: @nbro: Or it alludes the fact that that is the only way he knows how to do heap allocation.

Comment: for `std::vector<>` solution: When you do `T.resize(width*height);` early, it's close to best solution. If you would do `T.push_back(pixel);` without `reserve(width*height)`, it would be a bit inefficient. If you would do some kind of `insert(pos, pixel);` (on random positions), it would be really bad. ... the first option basically does what you had, with dynamic width*height.

Comment: @DomainFlag This problem has arisen many times. You can for example declare a pointer and when you create your variable of your particular struct, just allocate the memory as you already know (with the `new` operator) by accessing your pointer with the dot operator, if that's an operator.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, also, as he's just said.

Comment: @DomainFlag The TLDR is use a `std::vector<Color>`. If you allocate memory on the heap yourself, you'll have to make sure that you write the appropriate copy and move constructor/assignment operators as well as a destructor. If you don't do it correctly, you can leak memory, and that happens a lot. The downside to using a vector is that to write efficient code you'll want to make it a 1D vector which has implications for how you address pixels (2d vectors aren't contiguous like the array counterparts) and you'll need to research on size and capacity and why you need to use reserve wisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
//Switched to a class because we need some encapsulation or this will be bug-prone.
class matrixImage
{
    //Do you need this? What kind of object is "Image"?
    //Image Img;
    std::vector<Color> pixel_data;
    int Width;
    int Height;
public:
    matrixImage(int width = 1, int height = 1) :
    Width(width), Height(height), pixel_data(width * height) 
    {
    }

    //You can add bounds-checking if you need it, i.e. make sure y is less than Height, 
    //make sure x is less than Width. Not every application needs it, and you need a 
    //clear semantic of "what should happen" if you specify an invalid index.
    Color & get_color(int x, int y) {
        return pixel_data[y * Width + x];
    }
    //We have two versions to handle the case where your object is made "const"
    Color const& get_color(int x, int y) const{
        return pixel_data[y * Width + x];
    }

    //Hey, we can use the function we just defined above this one!
    void set_color(int x, int y, Color c) {
        get_color(x, y) = c;
    }

    //This only resizes the canvas. Doing proper "Resizing" is beyond the scope of what 
    //we're discussing here.
    void set_size(int new_width, int new_height) {
        std::vector<Color> new_data(new_width * new_height);

        //This case is pretty easy
        if(new_width == Width) {
            std::copy(
                pixel_data.begin(), 
                pixel_data.begin() + std::min(pixel_data.size(), new_data.size()), 
                new_data.begin()
            );
        //This gets complicated
        } else if(new_width < Width) {
            for(size_t y = 0; y < std::min(Height, new_height); y++) {
                std::copy(
                    pixel_data.begin() + y * Width,
                    pixel_data.begin() + y * Width + new_width,
                    new_data.begin() + y * new_width
                );
            }
        //Similar logic, but slightly different.
        } else {
            for(size_t y = 0; y < std::min(Height, new_height); y++) {
                std::copy(
                    pixel_data.begin() + y * Width,
                    pixel_data.begin() + (y + 1) * Width,
                    new_data.begin() + y * new_width
                );
            }
        }
        pixel_data = new_data;
        Width = new_width;
        Height = new_height;
    }

    //I leave this last one as an exercise to the reader, as it's beyond my expertise.
    void resize(int new_width, int new_height);
};
```

This will handle dynamic memory allocation for you (and of course, deallocation) and give you some basic functionality to work directly with the underlying data if you absolutely need to.

Comment: Bounds checking is trivial to add, just use `pixel_data.at(y * Width + x)` to access the vector.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Not quite. What if the user specifies an `x` value greater than `Width`? One would logically expect an error, but `pixel_data.at(y * Width + x)` will not throw an error in that case.

Comment: with a fast check on tutorials on vector, I changed something and part by part it starts to work, i'm gonna dive into to understand better the principles and so on. Don't judge me, I am just starting off c++ with less then 3 months of experience and it's always daunting for me to go to stack and to realize that I know too little. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You have the answer to your own question, which is to use a pointer in the struct. Then you would use `new` to get heap memory and store the result in your pointer.

But no, don't do this manually. Learn how to write "Modern C++" (look it up) which *almost never* uses `new` or `delete`, and for good reasons.

Use `std::vector` here. Really.

Ideally you would wrap this entire thing into some kind of `Bitmap` class which hides the vector and provides member functions to access pixels. Not virtual functions, because efficiency is very important for graphics.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <memory>

struct matrixImage
{
    Image Img;
    int Width;
    int Height;
    std::unique_ptr<Color[]> colors;
    Color& color(int x, int y);
};

Color& matrixImage::color(int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= Width || y >= Height)
        throw std::out_of_range("bad co-ordinates");
    return colors[y*Width + x];
}

// ...

matrixImage mimg;
mimg.Width = 20;
mimg.Height = 100;
mimg.colors = std::make_unique<Color>(mimg.Width*mimg.Height);
```

It would be better to encapsulate the allocation inside a constructor, that takes the width and height as arguments:

```
matrixImage::matrixImage(Image img, int width, int height)
: Img(img), Width(width), Height(height), colors(std::make_unique<Color>(mimg.Width*mimg.Height))
{ }
```

Comment: While this is technically a valid use of `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, it's not very ideomatic, and `std::vector<T>` is vastly preferable. Teaching the user how to do "dynamic memory allocation" doesn't have to mean teaching the literal use of pointers—and it probably shouldn't when the specific application is storing large amounts of data in a contiguous data structure. Also, this will make the object non-copyable unless the user manually adds a copy constructor.

Comment: @Xirema, you could have argued that using `vector` allows bounds-checking (which you didn't make use of in your answer for some reason), and makes the object copyable rather than move-only. Your comment makes no mention of such advantages though (nor the disadvantage of `vector` being three times the size of a `unique_ptr`).

Comment: @JonathanWakely The size of a vector vs a unique_ptr for this example will be in the noise. Given that the image size probably dwarfs the size of the actual container overhead, the real question is how much space on average is wasted from vector growth. If reserve is used properly I think it will be little to none, but I don't know how how the various libraries implement that.

Comment: @RyanP, yep, good points. In a case like this it _probably_ doesn't need to grow. The width and height are known, and you're unlikely to want to do `push_back` of individual pixels. Which is why I used a fixed size array, with zero overhead, managed by `unique_ptr`. A `std::vector` does a **lot** more, and most of it isn't needed in this case. It might still be the right answer though.